# Docker - Communication failure between containers on same network

Tags: django, angular, docker, networking, containers

I'm deploying an Angular - Django app on a Digital Ocean droplet. It's composed of 3 Docker containers:

- cards_front: the Angular front-end
- cards_api: the django rest framework back-end
- cards_db: the postgres database

They're all on the same network:

```
[
{
    "Name": "ivan_cards_api_network",
    "Id": "ddbd3524e02a7c918f6e09851731e015fdb7e8647358c5ed0c4cd949cf651fd9",
    "Created": "2018-10-09T23:44:33.293036243Z",
    "Scope": "local",
    "Driver": "bridge",
    "EnableIPv6": false,
    "IPAM": {
        "Driver": "default",
        "Options": null,
        "Config": [
            {
                "Subnet": "172.22.0.0/16",
                "Gateway": "172.22.0.1"
            }
        ]
    },
    "Internal": false,
    "Attachable": true,
    "Ingress": false,
    "ConfigFrom": {
        "Network": ""
    },
    "ConfigOnly": false,
    "Containers": {
        "0d3144b27eaf6d7320357b6d703566e489f672b09b61dba0caf311c6e1c4711c": {
            "Name": "cards_front",
            "EndpointID": "47b1f8f42c4d18afeafeb9da502fd0197e726f29bd6d3d3c2960b44737bd579a",
            "MacAddress": "02:42:ac:16:00:04",
            "IPv4Address": "172.22.0.4/16",
            "IPv6Address": ""
        },
        "3e9233f4bfc023632aaf13a146d1a50f75b4944503d9f226cf81140e92ccb532": {
            "Name": "cards_api",
            "EndpointID": "34d4780dc6f907a8cb9621223d6effe0a0aac1662d5272ae4a5104ba7f3808c4",
            "MacAddress": "02:42:ac:16:00:03",
            "IPv4Address": "172.22.0.3/16",
            "IPv6Address": ""
        },
        "e5e208a20523c2d41433b850dc64db175de8ee7d0d156e2917c12fd8ebdf97ab": {
            "Name": "cards_db",
            "EndpointID": "8a8f44bbcdf2f95e716e2763e33bed31e1d2bdbfae7f6d78c8dee33de426a7ef",
            "MacAddress": "02:42:ac:16:00:02",
            "IPv4Address": "172.22.0.2/16",
            "IPv6Address": ""
        }
    },
    "Options": {},
    "Labels": {
        "com.docker.compose.network": "cards_api_network",
        "com.docker.compose.project": "ivan",
        "com.docker.compose.version": "1.22.0"
    }
}
```

ALLOWED_HOSTS on django settings is set to ['*']

When I test the Angular front-end on the browser I get on Chrome's developer tools:

```
GET http://localhost:8000/themes net::ERR_CONNECTION_RESET
```

So, the Angular container is failing to communicate with the django container.

But if I do a curl localhost:8000/themes from inside the DO droplet I get a response.

I know there's something missing on the network configuration, but I can't figure out what it is.

Thank you

EDIT:

If I do a curl from inside the Angular container to the django container I get a response (the empty array):

```
root@90cea47dd13d:/# curl 172.22.0.3:8000/themes
[]
```

Comment: I am assuming you mean that when you are remotely hitting the droplet like `http://<droplet-ip>:8000` you get a connection error.

Comment: @ShawnC. I edited the post. I'm using the Angular app through the browser. The Angular container is the only one exposed to the port 80 of the DO droplet.

Comment: If you are remotely accessing via browser and the URL is localhost then you are not hitting the droplet

Comment: Yes, I'm hitting the Angular app (I can see the html that the app renders), but it's the angular app the one that calls the django backend. The error message that you see there is from chrome's developer tools. (I'm going to add that now).

Comment: My point is if you are hitting an angular app remotely then it should not be asking localhost for data.

Comment: Maybe you are right. The angular app is using the HttpClient to call http://localhost:8000/themes. If that's wrong, how should I be doing it then?